# Adding a dummy variable changes coefficients

Tags: r, linear-regression, dummy-variable

Should adding a dummy variable change coefficients for other explanatory variables in a linear model? 
I thought it would only change the intercept but the coefficients have changed for non-intercept terms as well.

Here is the example code with `mtcars` data (sourced from: 
http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/20516_29b941670a4b42688292b4bb892a660f.html

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars$am_text <- as.factor(mtcars$am)
levels(mtcars$am_text) <- c("Automatic", "Manual")


fit1 <- lm(mpg ~ am_text + wt, data = mtcars)
summary(fit1)

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ am_text + wt, data = mtcars)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.5295 -2.3619 -0.1317  1.4025  6.8782 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   37.32155    3.05464  12.218 5.84e-13 ***
am_textManual -0.02362    1.54565  -0.015    0.988    
wt            -5.35281    0.78824  -6.791 1.87e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.098 on 29 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7528,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7358 
F-statistic: 44.17 on 2 and 29 DF,  p-value: 1.579e-09
```

Now running a linear model with a subset data:

```
# Here is without dummy variable, but now with subset data
fit2 <- lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars[mtcars$am_text == "Automatic",])
summary(fit2)

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars[mtcars$am_text == "Automatic",])

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.6004 -1.5227 -0.2168  1.4816  5.0610 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  31.4161     2.9467  10.661 6.01e-09 ***
wt           -3.7859     0.7666  -4.939 0.000125 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.528 on 17 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5893,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5651 
F-statistic: 24.39 on 1 and 17 DF,  p-value: 0.0001246
```

Comment: This question seems to be better suited for CrossValidated. For what it is worth, dummy variables can change the coefficients of other explanatory variables when they are correlated with both the covariates and the response. There is nothing inherently different algebraically about how dummies and other variables are treated in OLS.

Comment: @tifu Noted. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the issue is that the slope coefficient in `fit1` is actually for both automatic and manual cars combined, even though each factor gets its own intercept. If you include an interaction term between `am_text` and `wt`as well (`am_text:wt`), then you can compare better with the model of only automatic cars (`fit2`).

```
fit3 <- lm(mpg ~ am_text + wt + am_text:wt, data = mtcars)
summary(fit3)

# Call:
# lm(formula = mpg ~ am_text * wt, data = mtcars)
# 
# Residuals:
#     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
# -3.6004 -1.5446 -0.5325  0.9012  6.0909 
# 
# Coefficients:
#                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)       31.4161     3.0201  10.402 4.00e-11 ***
# am_textManual     14.8784     4.2640   3.489  0.00162 ** 
# wt                -3.7859     0.7856  -4.819 4.55e-05 ***
# am_textManual:wt  -5.2984     1.4447  -3.667  0.00102 ** 
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 2.591 on 28 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.833,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.8151 
# F-statistic: 46.57 on 3 and 28 DF,  p-value: 5.209e-11
```

Notice now that the coefficients of `fit3` contain the intercept and slope of automatic cars by themselves, which matches those coefficients of `fit2`:

```
coef(fit2) # fit only to automatic
# (Intercept)          wt 
#   31.416055   -3.785908 

coef(fit3)
# (Intercept)    am_textManual               wt am_textManual:wt 
#   31.416055        14.878423        -3.785908        -5.298360
```

Comment: Thanks, totally forgot about the interaction term.

Answer (score 1):

In `lm`, when fitting a model using ordinary least square (OLS) you minimise the sum of squared residuals (SSR), which is a function of your model parameters. Typically in OLS there is no constraint on the parameters.

Adding parameters will therefore generally lead to different parameter estimates, as the OLS estimates simply correspond to those parameter values that minimise the SSR. If you add a dummy variable (or any other variable for that matter) `lm` will simply return those parameter estimates that lead to the lowest SSR. During the minimisation process all parameter values can vary freely.

For details, take a look at e.g. [the Wikipedia entry on OLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares) or any stats textbook.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are adding variables to your model, you should expect your coefficients to change. Remember, the coefficients for any variable are always with respect to the other variables present in the model.

If you have Y = aX1 + bX2 +cX3 + E, and you add an X4 to your model, you should expect that a, b, and c will change (unless X4 has no impact on the model at all).